# how to connect textfield with table view of listed options instead of keypad

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield

I need to be able to disable the keypad in a textfield, and instead when the user taps on it to start editing, a new table view will appear presenting a list of possible strings with which the textfield should be filled.

Anyone has any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

p.s. I tried already but this functionality cannot be nicely implemented with a picker in my case, as there are too many options to choose from and (more importantly) each one of them is a rather long string and cannot appear entirely in a picker.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need a regular cell that, when tapped, pushes a new detail UITableViewController with all the options to choose from. Once an option is chosen, set the cell's textLabel to whatever option have been selected.

If you'd like to go for an easier path, then you should also probably check the free Sensible TableView framework, as it has these kinds of cells out of the box (called selection cells). You just pass on your strings array to the selection cell and it will automatically display the detail view, and even assign the selected option to one of your object's properties if you wish. Should save you some good amount of manual work. Good luck!